# While en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, while

Quiero que en la consola también me diga los números enteros que puse ejemplo si puse 25 15 y 20 sin que estos se sumen, simplemente que en consola aparezca también ese dato.

```
let suma=0;
let cont=0;

while(suma<50){
    suma += parseInt(prompt("Pone un numero"));
    cont++
}
console.log(`la suma total es de: ${suma}`);
console.log(`El total de numeros introducidos es ${cont}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa `console.log()` dentro de tu ciclo:

```js
let suma=0;
let cont=0;

while(suma<50){
    let numero = parseInt(prompt("Pone un numero"));
    console.log(`Sumando: ${numero}`);
    suma += numero;
    cont++;
}

console.log(`la suma total es de: ${suma}`);
console.log(`El total de numeros introducidos es ${cont}`);
```

UPDATE:

Verificación de número, gracias a @quevedo

```js
let suma=0;
let cont=0;

while(suma<50){
    let numero = parseInt(prompt("Pone un numero"));
    if(!isNaN(numero)){
      console.log(`Sumando: ${numero}`);
      suma += numero;
      cont++;
    }
    else{
      alert("Eso no es un número");
    }
}

console.log(`la suma total es de: ${suma}`);
console.log(`El total de numeros introducidos es ${cont}`);
```

Comment: Todos son enteros por efecto de `parseInt(prompt("Pone un numero"));` debes verificar antes de aplicar parseInt